# How to formally prove that every sub-subsequence of $(a_n)_n$ is a subsequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, how do I **formally** prove that every subsequence of a subsequence of $(a_n)_n$ is actually a subsequence of $(a_n)_n$.

Comment: As with all things, a rigorous proof depends on your definitions. How do you define a sequence? How do you define a sub-sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $a=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of elements of some set $X$ is actually a function

$$a:\Bbb N\to X:n\mapsto a_n\;.$$

Suppose that $b=\langle a_{m_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a subsequence of $a$. This means simply that $m=\langle m_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is an increasing sequence in $\Bbb N$. That sequence $m$ is a strictly increasing function

$$m:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N:k\mapsto m_k\;,$$

and the subsequence $b$ is then just a composition: $b=a\circ m$, i.e., $b_k=a\big(m(k)\big)=a_{m_k}$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Conversely, if $m$ is any strictly increasing function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, $a\circ m$ is a subsequence of $a$.

Suppose that $c=\langle c_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a subsequence of $b$. Then there is a strictly increasing function $r:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that $c=b\circ r$. (That is, $c_k=b_{r_k}$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$.) And $b=a\circ m$, so

$$c=b\circ r=(a\circ m)\circ r=a\circ(m\circ r)\;,$$

since composition of functions is associative. The final step, which I’ll leave to you, is to verify that the composition of two strictly increasing functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ is a strictly increasing function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence, $(b_n)$ a subsequence of $(a_n)$, and $(c_n)$ a subsequence of $(b_n)$.

For every $n$, there is $M_n$ such that $a_{M_n} = b_n$. For every $n$, there is $K_n$ such that $b_{K_n} = c_n$.

Therefore, for every $n$, $$c_n = b_{K_n} = a_{M_{K_n}}$$

Comment: Technically, you need $M_n$ and $K_n$ are strictly increasing, I think, and then you need to show that $M_{K_n}$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Very true. Ugh, how irritating.